# How to get the body of a Request in OnResponse hook of Fastity Reply From

Tags: node.js, interceptor, fastify

I am using [Fastify HTTP proxy](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-http-proxy) in a service that act as a proxy that needs to inspect specific requests/response in the interaction between a client and a target server.
I found this solution that uses the `onResponse` hook:

```
const fastifyProxyLib = require("@fastify/http-proxy");

register(fastifyProxyLib, {
        ...proxyConfig, //some config
        upstream, //some url
        preHandler: async ({ url, body }) => {
          //Do something for specific url and body
        }
        replyOptions: {
          onResponse: (request, reply, res) => {
            console.log(res);
            reply.code(200).send(res);
          },
        }, 
}
```

Everything works well but I am not able to get the body of `res` in order to inspect what's inside its payload. The response correctly gets to the client where I use `axios` and I am able to see the correct body. Inside `reply.body` I got the body of the initial request instead. How can I inspect the `res`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `res` argument is a stream, so you need to consume it:

```
    onResponse: (request, reply, res) => {
      let data = '';
      res.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
      })
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('data is: ' + data);
        reply.code(200).send(data);
      })
    },
```

Adding an `onResponse` hook should work as well, without the need to consume the `res` object.
https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Hooks/#onresponse

Comment: Thanks @manuel, your solution seems to work. However, I do not understand the last part of your answer, I already use the onResponse hook

Comment: You can provide the `onRequest` hook as plugin parameter or as `fastify.addHook('onRequest', ...)`. 
Anyway I have tried but it is a stream, so you would need to consume that in any case.